# How to select random limited rows providing number of rows in where clause based on condition of your choice

Tags: mysql

this is my table structure:

```
id | Risk

1  | Low
2  | Low
3  | High
4  | Low
5  | High
6  | High
7  | High
8  | Low
9  | High
```

Now I know that there are total `4 Low` and `5 High`.

What I want to achieve is to get `5 random rows` where `3 rows from 'Low'` and `2 rows from 'High'`

This is my try:

```
SELECT *, 
(Select risk from myTable where risk = "Low" LIMIT 3) as lowRisk, 
(Select risk from myTable where risk = "High" LIMIT 2) as highRisk 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 5
```

I know subquery should return 1 row. Again I want something like this and this is my try code to explain you what I mean.

I am searching solution from 2 days.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 2 days? If it was just 3 random rows from 'low', could you solve it?

Comment: Yes, i am unable to achieve this with 1 query

Comment: I think it is not possible in MySQL

Comment: Why do you imagine that? Anyway show us what you think is possible.

Comment: I am unable to solve. how i can show? I need some help

Comment: union, subquery, join nothing working with this question

Comment: it says error message 'you cannot use limit in subquery'

Comment: This is a trivially simple problem. We just like to see that you have made some effort at resolving it yourself.

Comment: i wrote 2 days, that means i played with it so much

Comment: and it is not simple. i need total 5 rows where 3 from low and 2 from high

Comment: I want something like this `SELECT *, (Select risk from myTable where risk = "Low" LIMIT 3) as lowRisk, (Select risk from myTable where risk = "High" LIMIT 2) as highRisk FROM `myTable` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5` I know subquery should return 1 row. Just help me out how to achieve this.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rKPdQPaDqo7r8JZcS6a5Rj/0

Comment: Thank you so much your solved example is the one I wanted

Comment: I was using Select ...where risk = "Low" LIMIT 3 UNION ALL Select ...where risk = "High" Limit 2 order by rand() and it was not working

Comment: You may write your answer in answer box so that I can mark as tick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE Risk = 'Low' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE Risk = 'High' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2) 
-- uncomment if needed
-- ORDER BY RAND()
```

Study [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  UNION Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Pay attention - if there is no specified (in LIMIT) amount of rows for some `Risk` value then total amount of rows in the output will be less than 5.